# Can't install ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server Windows server 2012r2

Tags: sql-server, odbc

Any idea? No logs, no problems found anywhere, simply this screen, installation interrupted and try again... Why?

[image]

Comment: I suggest you reboot and run the install as and administrator.

Comment: can't rebot for now :S still waiting...

Answer (score 0):

Look in the event logs. Open Windows Event Viewer: Control Panel / Administrative Tools.

Comment: Is there a downlevel driver that needs to be uninstalled?

Answer (score 0):

Finally rebooting the system worked ;)